# PUBNUB integration in android -forbbiden exception

Tags: android, pubnub

Hi I am trying to integrate pubnub- a real time chatting client available in 70 + languages.

i registered my self with the developer console and got PUbLISHER_KEY and SUBSCRIBER_KEY.when ever i am trying to publish message by passing publish key and subscribe key i am getting forbbiden exception.

if i am passing "demo" and "demo" as those keys i am able establish connection to pubnub.

can any one help me how to resolve this issue . a sample app in android is more help full.

Comment: Could you share more about what the exception says? Also have you enabled PAM on the developer console?

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.I have added PAM and trying to intialize the pubnub class.it is giving me forbiden exception.

Comment: With PAM enabled evey instance of the PubNub object will need an auth key. Will post a more full answer shortly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The forbidden exception is happening since you have PubNub Access Manager (PAM) enabled. Once enabled, all access to PubNub on your pub/sub keys is blocked unless access has been granted.

If you want your keys to work right away, simple log on to [your admin console](https://admin.pubnub.com) and disable Access Manager on your account until you are ready to implement it.

For more information on Access Manager, see the following links.

Grant Access: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html#grant

Read more about PAM: http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/access-manager/

Security with PAM: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/overview/security.html